# Dynamic number of series with one query in Grafana

Tags: postgresql, grafana

Is there a way to get multiple series in one query using Postgres connection in Grafana? Let’s say I have 5 attributes associated to my data and I’d like to display 5 series using one query so it’s dynamic.

When one attribute is added or removed, so is done with series.

```
attribute | bits    | created_at
------------------------------
1         | 44632   | <datetime>
4         | 124854  | <datetime>
2         | 488     | <datetime>
2         | 8       | <datetime>
4         | 384332  | <datetime>
3         | 44632   | <datetime>
1         | 6732    | <datetime>
3         | 162     | <datetime>
```

Example query:

```
SELECT
    $__time(created_at),
    sum(bits),
    attribute
FROM
    table
WHERE
    $__timeFilter(created_at)
GROUP BY created_at, attribute
ORDER BY created_at;
```

and attribute has distinct values (1, 2, 3, 4) so I get 4 different series, each showing data for specific attribute’s value using some kind of similar query.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you would want to group based on attribute, like you are doing in the example.

The exact query you would need is something like this:

```
SELECT
    $__time(created_at),
    attribute as metric,
    sum(bits)        
FROM
    table
WHERE
    $__timeFilter(created_at)
GROUP BY created_at, attribute
ORDER BY created_at;
```

by giving the 'metric' alias to attribute, it will be picked up as the name of the individual timeseries and the grouping should take care of the rest

Comment: Oh, Nice. This was no where to be found, thanks a lot!

Comment: @simPod there is a docs page for the Postgres data source that describes how a query should be built (including `as metric`): http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/postgres/#time-series-queries It also describes other types of queries: table queries, template variable queries and annotations queries.

Comment: Thanks, completely missed that metric mention there before.

Comment: this worked exactly as required. I didnt even know how to use the metric and this example was clean and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Using Grafana v9.0.9, I needed to add a `Multi-frame time series` transformation.

With `Transform` => `Prepare time series` => Format: `Multi-frame time series`:

[image: grafana screenshot]

It seems that the `metric` alias is not required anymore using this

Comment: It took me much longer than I thought would be required to find this information. Seems like a pretty basic feature that I couldn't find info on anywhere. Thanks! I'm curious how you figured this out though. :)